# Powershell command to identify all the Windows type and UNIX type text file

Tags: powershell

The GIT is messing up few files and it saves the unix based files in **LF** format in the system.

There is also few of the windows file that gets saved in **CR LF** format.

I need to differentiate between the UNIX based file and Windows based file.

I was able to successfully write the below code for 1 text file. The below returned TRUE as it is a windows file.

```
PS C:\Desktop\SecretSauce> (GET-CONTENT 'HIDEME.TXT' -raw) -match "\r\n$"
```

Question:

There are 1000's of files in different format(txt, cpp, hpp, sql) in both **LF** and **CR LF** format in the same location.

I need to get the output with the path of file, filename with extension and True (If it is **CR LF**) and False (if it is **LF**).

when I execute this command to check for multiple files, output is not returning any result.

```
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\Desktop\SecretSauce\*.*' -raw) -match "\r\n$"
```

What is the best approach for this using powershell ?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to fix your GIT setup to apply proper line breaks the way you want them during upload/download?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thats in the plan. But in the meantime, I thought I will come up with this approach. At present no issues, but it does complicate the verification of deployments because files will show as “different” if the types are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an expensive approach, because each file is read in full, but the following should do what you want:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -File -Path H:\Desktop\Parent_Folder\Sub-Folder2\*.* |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      HasCRLF = (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $_.FullName) -match '\r\n'
      Name = $_.Name
      FullName = $_.FullName
    }
  }
```

You'll see output such as the following:

```
HasCRLF Name     FullName
------- ----     --------
  False foo.txt  H:\Desktop\Parent_Folder\Sub-Folder2\foo.txt
   True bar.txt  H:\Desktop\Parent_Folder\Sub-Folder2\bar.txt
```

Comment: This is amazing. I understand it takes more time but gives me what I needed.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Learning_something_new.